# this "scrollTop" does not work well in firefox only in chrome how can I change it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

*scrollTop* not working in Firefox

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var NextScroll = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if  (NextScroll >= 800){
        jQuery('#logomacchia').addClass("maccancello");
    } else {
        jQuery('#logomacchia').removeClass("maccancello");
    }
});
```

In chrome it works, the class is activated, but in Firefox it does not work, I scroll the page but the class is not added.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Use This Code :**

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
  if( jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= 800 ) {
    jQuery('#logomacchia').addClass("maccancello");
  } else {
    jQuery('#logomacchia').removeClass("maccancello");
  }
});
```

Comment: Please clear your browser cache or check site in private windows and let us know your thoughts. Please Send me siteurl